# fetch and render api into Dom

Tags: node.js, function, api

[my console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZH3u.jpg)

I have a problem rendering data in HTML, I am getting the object in the console without any error but nothing is showing in the DOM. You can see in the code below.

```
fetch("api/meals")
  .then(res => {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    let root = `
<h2>meals API</h2>
`;
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(response, array => {
      const {
        id,
        title,
        description,
        location,
        when,
        max_reservation,
        price,
        created_date
      } = array;
      root += `

<h5>meal ID: ${id}</h5>
<ul class="w3-ul">
  <li>title : ${title}</li>
  <li>description : ${description}</li>
  <li>location : ${location}</li>
  <li>when : ${when}</li>
  <li>max_reservation : ${max_reservation}</li>
  <li>price : ${price}</li>
  <li>created_date : ${created_date}</li>
</ul>
</div>
`;
      document.getElementById("root").innerHTML = root;
    });
  });
```

Comment: Can you log whats in root?
Also you could have called forEach on array directly as so
[1,2,3].forEach((item)=>{console.log(item);})

Comment: check if `document.getElementById("root")` return element in the console, this might be your issue since, I assume, you don't have errors.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have just edit my question above and add the print screen of my console. Have look and tell me what to do.

Comment: @Hemant, from were I have to put the console.log to find out  whats in root?thanks

Comment: Just before this line    document.getElementById("root").innerHTML = root;
BTW I just ran your code with dummy data in response object.
If you have any element with id 'root', your code should give expected result.

Comment: I try it but I din't get anything. Here is my html file: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <title>Meal sharing website</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Meal sharing</h1>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <img src="pondu.jpg" alt="" />
    <script src="meals.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: You have issue with head tag.
Please check jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hemanthepat/L091g7jq/4/

Comment: I have the same problem even correct the head issue {<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Meal sharing website</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>List of meals</h2>
    <img src="shop.png" alt="shop" />
    <script src="meals.js"></script>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>}